# GitLab CI trigger pipeline when branch/tag is removed

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Git repo. GitLab CI is configured to deploy artifacts to orphan branch 'artifacts/$BRANCH'.

<sub>(It may be that is not a best way to store artifacts, but it is convenient enough for that project purposes)</sub>

I want to detect a moment when BRANCH is deleted (merged&removed), and then run CI job to remove corresponding `artifacts/$BRANCH`. I looked for a solution in docs, found keywords [`only`/`except`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic) but there was nothing suitable.

At the moment I have the only idea to run clean up job with every pipeline and/or scheduled. A really cool solution would be 'trigger pipeline when branch removed'. Is this possible?

Comment: It looks like answer material has been merged into the question. Would you roll this back please, and expand on your answer instead?

Comment: In the absence of a discussion, I've rolled this back to the original question state. Questions are best if they do not refer to answers, except in rare cases where a clearly delineated "update" at the end asks a closely related additional question. The Q&A format we have here makes more sense if answers are a direct response to the question posed, and if the two are not intermingled.

Comment: @halfer, Source code you removed is important, what can we discuss without sources?

Comment: I intepreted "See more at the end of the answer" to mean that the source code was effectively answer material, and thus I believe(d) it should go in the answer. If it is part of the question (i.e. that was the initial context before finding the answer) then I'd be happy to restore it, but it would be best if it did not refer to the answer (since you could not have known about the answer when you first wrote it).

Comment: Basically, answers should flow naturally from questions, as this chronology makes them easier to understand. If one needs to read an answer to understand a question, that's confusing for new readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround idea has been implemented:

```
before_script:
- function DEBUG { >&2 "$@" || true; }

remove_stale_artifacts:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
  image: alpine
  variables:
    GIT_CHECKOUT: "false"
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: none
  script:
  - apk add --no-cache git perl openssh-client
  - mkdir /temp  &&  mount -t tmpfs -o size=50m tmpfs /temp
  ## --- FIND STALED ARTIFACTS BRANCHES ---
  - git branch -r  --list origin/artifacts/\* | grep -v HEAD | sed -e s#origin/##g -Ee s#^\\s+##g >/temp/ARTIFACTS_BRANCHES
  - DEBUG cat /temp/ARTIFACTS_BRANCHES
  - git branch -r  --list origin/\*           | grep -v -e HEAD -e artifacts/| sed -e s#origin/##g -Ee s#^\\s+#artifacts/#g >/temp/BRANCHES
  - DEBUG cat /temp/BRANCHES
  - fgrep -vf /temp/BRANCHES /temp/ARTIFACTS_BRANCHES >/temp/STALE_ARTIFACTS_BRANCHES || return 0
  - DEBUG cat /temp/STALE_ARTIFACTS_BRANCHES
  - PUSH_SPEC=$(sed -e 's#\s+##g' -e 's#^#:#g' /temp/STALE_ARTIFACTS_BRANCHES)
  - DEBUG echo "$PUSH_SPEC"
  ## --------- URL --------------
  - echo "$KI" >/tmp/ki  &&  chmod 400 /tmp/ki
  - export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i/tmp/ki -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no"
  - SSH_URL=$(echo "$CI_REPOSITORY_URL" | perl -pe 's#https://(.+?):(.+?)@(.+?)/(.+?).git#git@\3:\4.git#' )
  - git push "$SSH_URL" $PUSH_SPEC
```

Where KI is a variable which contains private SSH key. Should be set in RepoSettings->CI->Variables. Public key should be added to deployment keys, and write access should be allowed.